# Define "const int" from double variables

Tags: c++11, types

I need to define obtain a "const int Iteration" to define the array "a[Iteration]". Iteration is derived from 2 "double variables". With below, I can not successfully define a[Iteration]. please help. thanks

```
    double Range=9.4;
    double Step=2.2;
    const int Iteration=(int)(Range/Step);

    int a[Iteration]={0};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, if your variables are not compile-time constants (which they should be when `constexpr`), you'll need to change the type of `a`:

```
double Range=9.4;
double Step=2.2;
const int Iteration=(int)(Range/Step);

std::vector<int> a_v(Iteration);
std::unique_ptr<int[]> a_u(new int[Iteration]());
// or simply, but not recommended
int *a_p(new int[Iteration]());
// don't forget to delete[] a_p afterwards
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I adopt the pointer to process the array.

Answer (score 1):

`Range` and `Step` are not *constant expressions*, therefore `Iteration` isn't either. The array bound must be a *constant expression*.

You can use the `constexpr` keyword to ensure that your variables are initialized from *constant expressions* and are themselves recognized as *constant expressions* by the compiler:

```
constexpr double Range=9.4;
constexpr double Step=2.2;
constexpr int Iteration=(int)(Range/Step);

int a[Iteration]={0};
```

Comment: thank you for suggestion. Unfortunately, my VC is 2012 version that does not support "constexpr".  I have to stay on VC 2012 as my tester VC template requires this version.